# New Entity being added every time i Perform a ancestor load query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

So every time i perform the query api below instead of listing all the expenses created by the user it creates a new one?

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "getMyExpenses",
        path = "getMyExpenses",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST
)
public List<Expense> getMyExpenses(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("You need to authorisation");
    }
    String userId = user.getUserId();
    Key<Person> personKey = Key.create(Person.class, userId);
    return ofy().load().type(Expense.class).ancestor(personKey).list();
}
```

Im not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Also the problem may be with how i tried to defined the parent relationship?  here is my Expense model class.

```
@Entity
public class Expense {
    @Id Long ExpenseId;
    String name;
    @Parent
    Ref<Person> ExpenseCreator;
    int amount;

    private  Expense() {}
    public Expense(Long expenseId, String name, int amount) {
        ExpenseId = expenseId;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Long getExpenseId() {
        return ExpenseId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }


}
```

Comment: What does `Key<Person> personKey = Key.create(Person.class, userId);` do?

Comment: This piece of code will certainly not create a new expense entity. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @DanCornilescu `Key.create()` should be the Objectify/datastore helper method to create a `Key` object in-memory. It doesn't perform a datastore operation.

Comment: @konqi I've now added the expense model class to the question too since i may have defined the relationship wrong?

Comment: The entity looks alright. Although if you create a constructor that fills in all fields you should add parent reference as well since it's actually required. It's also best practice in Java to use camelCase for evertyhing that cannot be instantiated. I'm guessing you create `Expense` entities without setting the parent properly. That is pure speculation though, since the provided code does not perform any datastore writes.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it's not in this code. Look for code that save()es an entity. _That_ code is where entity creation happens. Never in a query.

Comment: I can confirm that it was indeed some code  in the insert expense. It was not actually assigning a parent while creating them. Thanks for the help guys(@konqi , @stickfigure). I really appreciate it. although i do think there should be more documentation since  the reason this problem occured is i did not know how to how to initialize constructors with a parent. Furthermore i have changed ref to Key since i do not know how to use it.

Comment: I'm glad you found the source of the problem. I disagree on the documentation thing though. I find the datastore and objectify documentations quite good. Since you don't have to use constructors at all this is not documented. It is however very well documented what an entity key is and that it consists of ancestor, kind, id/name. The connection between those and the `@Parent` & `@Id` objectify annotations should be obvious enough, but it is also documented.